# How can I make a new shape patches using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Now, I just use the Rectangle patches in my plot by using matplotlib, but I 'd like to make my own patches. How should I have to do if I want to use my own design patches? Is there any good ideas to make the patches manually?
If you guys have some good idea, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it answered your question - that way the question is marked as such for future users.

Comment: Oh! I see. I will do that! It was really helpful to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`matplotlib.patches.Polygon`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html) to create patches of arbitrary shape by specifying the desired vertices, here is an example

```py
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

xy = [[0, 0], 
      [1, 0], 
      [1.5, 0.5], 
      [1, 1], 
      [0, 1]]

p = Polygon(xy)
plt.gca().add_patch(p)
plt.xlim([-0.5,2])
plt.ylim([-0.5,1.5])
plt.show()
```

And the output:

[image]